# Making navbar-brand bigger font makes it overlap the nav-items in older Safari

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to make navbar-brand bigger font in Bootstrap 4 beta navbar-component.

I override the navbar-brand and apply font-size and it works fine on all the modern browsers

```
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
  <a class="navbar-brand" routerLink="start">Nordic Sounds</a>

  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent"
    aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>


  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item pb-0 mb-0">
        <a class="nav-link pb-0" routerLink="search" routerLinkActive="active">
          Read the book
        </a>
      </li>

      <li class="nav-item pb-0 mb-0" *ngFor="let page of applicationStateService.getAllPages()">
          <a class="nav-link pb-0" [routerLink]="['page', page.id]" routerLinkActive="active">
        {{ page.title }}
          </a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item p-0 m-0" *ngIf="!applicationStateService.isProductionBuild()">
        <a class="nav-link pb-0" routerLink="admin" [routerLinkActive]="['active']">
          Admin
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Here's the CSS I add to navbar-brand to make the font bigger:

```
.navbar-brand {
    font-family: "lato" !important;
    font-weight: 700 !important;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 1.9em;
    color: #393939;
}
```

However, on some older Safari (like on El Capitan 10.11), the bigger I make the navbar-brand, the more it starts to overlap the first nav-item next to it.

Older Safari (the white font is because I'm hovering it by accident when capturing):
[image: This is how it looks like in older Safari]

Modern browser:
[image: This is how it looks in any modern browser]

When I inspected the element on this older Safari, it seems that the container is smaller than the actual font element so basically the font overflows the container. If I remove "display: flex" from ".navbar" on the older Safari, then the "display: -webkit-box" becomes dominant and the layout works. However, it flows incorrectly in the mobile layout.

Comment: post your HTML and css code

Comment: We need to see your HTML/CSS which is causing your problem, along with what you have tried to fix it. Also it would be helpful if you could post screenshots of expected vs actual results in the browser.

Comment: Added HTML/CSS and a screen capture. Sorry!

Comment: I found some new info and added it on edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve this. I guess it's hacky, since it should work right out of the box, but anyway.

What caused the issue (don't know why) was that on older Safari the .navbar has both "display: flex" and "display: -webkit-box". If I disabled "display: flex", then "display: -webkit-box" took over and it worked on desktop. But when the mobile accordion menu activated, then the layout flowed incorrectly.

So I just needed to add "display: -webkit-box !important" to
1) override "display: flex" on the browsers that support it
2) to affect the desktop version only:

```
.navbar {
    // Fixes menu on old Safari by overriding display: flex on desktop-view
    @include media-breakpoint-up(md) {
        display: -webkit-box !important;
    }
}
```

Please note that the breakpoint has to correspond to the navbar-expand-{xs/sm/md/lg/xl} that you have on the .navbar.

I tested on latest Chrome, Firefox and Edge and they didn't mind this CSS and worked as before.

Answer (score 0):

target safari by using media query like below and resize the font

```css
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {
  #your-id {
    font-size: 13px;
  }
}
```

Comment: This would probably target the modern Safari browsers as well? The problem only occurs in Safari a couple of OSs back.